# What is the difference between "toward" and "towards"?

Tags: vocabulary

I only know "`towards`" and always use it before today: "`move towards`", etc. But today, I come across `toward`, after referring the dictionary, I find I can't differentiate them clearly. What is the difference between "`toward`" and "`towards`"? How can use them?

Comment: Not much. [Similar remarks on _beside_ and _besides_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/besides.html).

Answer (score -1):

OALD has: towards, also toward, especially AmE.

Comment: perhaps the OP (original poster) is unaware of what OALD stands for, not everyone is familiar with the acronyms used on this site. This also includes AmE.

Comment: OALD - Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/towards?q=towards.  BrE British English, AmE  American English.

Comment: If it has both toward and towards, that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Toward is a graphical variant of towards, meaning it is the same word which can be spelt in 2 different ways.

Comment: *Graphical* variant? I would take that to mean they are pronounced the same, but as far as I know that's never the case.

Comment: Why would you assume the same pronunciation?

Comment: Because "graphical variant" to me implies that the variance is solely graphical. If it's both a graphical and oral variant, I would expect it to just be called a "variant".